# How update specific element column json postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

The next sql statement fail

```
update table set field->>'index' = '' WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

For me following SQL statement works:

```sql
UPDATE public.table SET field = field::jsonb || '{"index":"newvalue"}'::jsonb 
WHERE condition
```

This works, if the column is of type `json` or `jsonb`.